# What kind of distribution it is if I simply multiply values from two independent normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

I think the question I recently posted was ambiguous. So I refined it.

[Is the product of the same two independent normal distribution also a normal distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4809906/is-the-product-of-the-same-two-independent-normal-distribution-also-a-normal-dis)

My question is about the distribution of returns when I invest an ETF multiple years consequently.

For example, I can assume that annual gains of SPY(S&P500 ETF) follow a normal distribution e.g. $N(10\%, 20\%^2)$.

If I invest 10 years on SPY, what kind of cumulative gain distribution I can see?

I could simulate it by calculating $(1 + N(10\%, 20\%^2))^{10}$ or $N(110\%, 20\%^2)^{10}$ multiple times and plotted histogram in a graph.

It was not a normal distribution which I expected. So I'm curious about the name of the distribution. Here is the graph I plotted. (1, 2, 5, and 10 multiplications)
[Distributions of multiplications of 1, 2, 5, and 10 the same normal distributions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZbtT.png)

(ADDED) one more question,
If I apply a log function to the result values, will it be a normal distribution? It looks like that. I attached a log graph.
[A log graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amxPL.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the product of the same two independent normal distribution also a normal distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4809906/is-the-product-of-the-same-two-independent-normal-distribution-also-a-normal-dis)

Comment: Partly. that was my previous question. I understood the result is not a normal distribution from the kind commenter. But I couldn't guess the name of the distribution.

Comment: See the [Normal Product Distribution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html)